# Using a ArcGIS Server Feature Service's addFeature method: Parameters?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, arcgis-rest-api

I am wanting to post data back to a feature service using the addFeatures method on a feature service.  [Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/fsadd.html) it says to use a query and an esri rep says to use a query task.  But my "Query" object doesn't seem to have a "features" definition as suggested in the linked doc page above where they say the parameters table.  Anyone have any ideas on how to do the addFeatures.

```
QueryTask queryTask =
                new QueryTask("http://server/ArcGIS/rest/services/geoprocessing/featureServiceName/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures");

            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query query = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Query();
            query.???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addFeatures method is part of the ArcGIS Server REST API, and while the ArcGIS Silverlight API uses the REST API to interface with ArcGIS Server, the two APIs don't correspond directly.

If you are using the Silverlight API, adding features is an edit task. [Here is a good overview of editing with the Silverlight API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#/Editing_features/016600000017000000/). and there are a few different approaches listed in the [samples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm).

Alternatively, you could write your own code that generated the REST API calls you wanted, might be a better option depending on your application.

Comment: This was just clearing in my head and reading your answer cemented it.  Thanks.